# Can't figure out either box-sizing, media queries or javascript

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Can't for the life of me figure this one out. I'm building a site: http://ingenious.jit.su/ and I've set up a sidebar that follows you down part of the page. I was pretty damn happy with it until I discovered this bug.

If you open in in Chrome on a Windows machine, and you resize the browser width to between 781 and 798 ish, the sidebar becomes fixed over the content of the page : (

For some reason it seems my media query is activating before dropping below the max-screen width of 780px.

Any help would rock!

Comment: +1 because I had similar problem recently and couldn't fix it .. the joys of webkit.

Comment: have you tried for a small page content to see if not the srollbar  affects the browser size.?

Comment: does it work if you reload in the resized state of you page?

Comment: If I reload in the resized state I still the issue, yes. That's because I have event handlers for the load event in addition to resize and scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's a couple ways to tackle this. Your JavaScript is causing your `#followbar`to be fixed, and you could either make edits there, or just add this to your css under your `@media screen and (max-width: 780px)`

```
#followbar
{
    position:static !important;
}
```

That's just a quick fix. Your JavaScript could probably use a bit of tweaking, but this will handle it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Any hints for the JavaScript?

Comment: You know, instead of using relative or inherit, use static. That should handle every issue I can see.

Comment: Your JavaScript is doing its job. I think what could be going on is that the 780px media query is triggering before the one for JavaScript is, so JavaScript is still acting as though we're on the desktop version, while the CSS is applying mobile features. If you edited that value, instead of if(width > 780/*this value*/) that would probably do it. But the CSS fix should do the trick.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I can't see a reason for the media query to trigger early. The only thing that makes any sense to me is positioning. I use a *{box-sizing: border-box} reset (with all the appropriate prefixes of course) and I think that might be pushing the sidebar out of it's display inline-block location. But I haven't been able to fix it with that approached either.